# How to apply easing functions to this jumping wave animation

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I have this animation using `Math.sin`: (draw function is called many times with increasing tick value)

```
const draw = (ctx, { w, h, tick }) => {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);  
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';

  const jump = 10;

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const sfx = Math.sin(i + tick * 0.1) * jump;

    let x = w / 2 + i * 15,
        y = h / 2;

       y += sfx;

    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
  }
};
```

Now I want different animation, probably using some easing function I don't know but I want the wave effect, like this:

```
.......
./\....
   /\
../  \.
..../\.
.......
```

```js
const draw = (ctx, { w, h, tick }) => {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);  
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';

  const jump = 10;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const sfx = Math.sin(i + tick * 0.1) * jump;
    
    let x = w / 2 + i * 15,
        y = h / 2;
        
       y += sfx;
        
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
  }
};

function init() {
  const w = 256,
      h = 256;
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = w;
canvas.height = h;

document.body.append(canvas);

  let tick = 0;
  new Loop(dt => {
    tick++;
    draw(ctx, { w, h, tick});
  }).start();
};

// Loop Library

const perf = window.performance !== undefined ? window.performance : Date;

const now = () => perf.now();

const raf = window.requestAnimationFrame;

function Loop(fn) {

  let running = false,
      lastUpdate = now(),
      frame = 0;

  this.start = () => {
    if (running) {
      return this;
    }
    running = true;
    lastUpdate = now();
    frame = raf(tick);
    return this;
  };

  this.stop = () => {
    running = false;
    if (frame != 0) {
      raf.cancel(frame);
    }
    frame = 0;
    return this;
  };

  const tick = () => {
    frame = raf(tick);
    const time = now();
    const dt = time - lastUpdate;
    fn(dt);
    lastUpdate = time;
  };

}

init();
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eguneys/7h1ndqog/15/ example code

Comment: on a second thought it looks like a sin function with a big period.